# OpenFileDialog filtering file names

Tags: vb.net

I am opening file dialog at shown way but I need some advanced functionality if possible.

```
    With OpenFileDialog_Restore
        .Title = "Choose archive to open"
        .InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(tempArch)
        .Filter = "My archives (*.7z;*.tar)|*.7z;*.tar|All Files(*.*) |*.*"
        .AddExtension = True
        .ShowDialog()
    End With
```

During to my program needs I would like to have shown ONLY files of asked type (not directories) but with ONLY file names which contain word "archive" inside name.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: No.  You could only use the FileOk event to reject a selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your filter accordingly.

```
With OpenFileDialog_Restore
    .Title = "Choose archive to open"
    .InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(tempArch)
    .Filter = "My archives (*.7z;*.tar)|*archive*.7z;*archive*.tar|All Files(*.*) |*.*"
    .AddExtension = True
    .ShowDialog()
End With
```

Comment: user409762, thank you. I can improve much my dialog with your suggestion. Is here a way to exclude directories and some shortcut files from my list?